# What is a "goodboy/badboy"

Tags: radare2, crackme

I'm confused and I'm trying to follow the [Radare 2 Crackme Challanges](https://dustri.org/b/defeating-ioli-with-radare2.html). In it, they say,

> This seems to be a goodboy/badboy.

Is a "goodboy/badboy" lingo for a specific thing, and if so what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251568/what-is-a-badboy-in-reverse-engineering

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about colloquialisms

Comment: @SYS_V what's the difference between a technical colloquialism, and "terminology"

Comment: if it was about terminology instead of slang I would still vote to close

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: I recall that terminology in Lena151's reversing tutorials. When changing program execution program flow she designates the desired function calls / modules (like congratulatory dialog boxes) as "good boy" and the undesired calls/subroutines (like early exit) as "bad boy"

Answer (score 4):

The "good boy" is the thing that lets you know you were successful in your cracking/patching. The "bad boy" is the thing that lets you know you're unsuccessful.

In a commercial app, a "good boy" would be akin to a message box saying, "Thank you for entering a valid license! You're now fully registered." Whereas the "bad boy" would be the message box that says, "I'm sorry. That's an invalid license. Please enter a valid license."